# C# Using a delegate to a member function to create a new thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, pointer-to-member

I'd like to create a new thread for a member function. I currently use this code,

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(c.DoSomethingElse));
thread.Start();
```

and it's working. But now I'd like to parameterize the member function.

I have this class:

```
class C1 {
  public void DoSomething() {}
  public void DoSomethingElse() {}

  public delegate void myDelegate(C1 c);
}
```

Then I have this function in some other class:

```
public void myFunction(C1.myDelegate func) {
  C1 c = new C1();

  func(c);  // this is working

  // but I want that the called function runs in it's own thread
  // so I tried...
  Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart( func(c) ); // but the compile wants a
  thread.Start();                                        // method name and not a delegate
}
```

I call the myFunction as follows...

```
myFunction( (c) => c.DoSomething() );
```

So is it possible to do this. I mean, I can pass the delegate und call it with the object func(c). And I can create a new thread passing an object.memberfunction. But I don't know how to combine both, using the memberfunction delegate and passing it to the ThreadStart function. Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using the Parallelism built into .NET.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => func(c));
```

Comment: I didn't notice the answers refresh but yes @DasKrümelmonster had the same idea just before me.  Follow his link.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use another overload of `Thread.Start(parameter)`

```
new Thread(c.DoSomethingElseWithParameter).Start(someparameter);
```

**Edit:**

For your own delegate try this.

```
   Thread thread = new Thread(() =>  func(c));
   thread.Start();
```

Note: your method signature should be of `void MethodName(object obj)` if not use a `Lambda` or `Anonymous method`

Comment: Isn't this the same as the first block in by question? Starting a thead for a hardcoded memberfunction is working. But inside myFunction I don't have a DoSomething or DoSomethingElse, I only have a func delegate or whatever I can pass to myFunction. So how can I parameterize the DoSomethingElseWithParameters from the outsite of myFunction?

Comment: So you want to pass delegate or pass parameter to function in a thread?

Comment: @bebo I've updated my answer check it out. and my answer isn't same as your question, pls read my `Note:` section carefully. if your method has `different signature` use a `Lambda` or `Anonymous method`. I mentioned clearly.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => func(c));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to 4.0, I recommend using the Task Parallel Library. Here's an example based on your code.

```
class TPL
{
    public delegate void myDelegate(object cgf);

    public static void Test(myDelegate func)
    {
        object c = new object();
        Task t = new Task(() => func(c));
        t.Start();
    }
}
```

Here's a link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The TPL is worth  looking at, especially the [StartNew Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew.aspx).
It uses a Threadpool instead of explicit threads, so it might even be better performing.

You can pass a lambda exression as parameter. I've done that, worked smoothly.